# Remove polygon from leaflet map on button click

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I have leaflet map which contain multiple polygons. I am adding polygon(s) to map like this

```
L.polygon([lat,lng]).addTo(map)
```

Also i can **draw** polygon on leaflet map. Now i want to remove specific polygon on button click event in typescript angular.
How can i achieve this functionality? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can save polygon added in a variable and register `click` listener on it and then remove it in the click event handler. Something like:

```
const polygon = L.polygon([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
polygon.on('click', function () {
  polygon.remove();
});
```

Comment: It worked.
But how can i identify that which polygon user want to remove? Is any polygon click event exist? Like if user first click on remove button and then click on polygon and that polygon will be removed?

Comment: @HunzlaSheikh It depends on behavior of your UI. If you want to allow user to click on a button first and then latter remove all polygons user click on you can do that.

Comment: Ok thanks. Also do you have any idea how to remove specific polygon which i draw?
For example this.polygonDrawer = new L.Draw.Polygon(this.map); Now how i remove this? I am currently using clearLayers function but it remove all layers/polygons and i want to remove specific layer?

Comment: You can add a toggle button in your UI, when Button is active then user can delete any polygon otherwise no event or some other function (like popup) runs on the click of polygon